# How to fetch data from json api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to fetch json data in html page, all data are fetching but only one data is not fetching why? here is my code.

This is my json data and I have to fetch "classified_id" but it is showing undefined.

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "classification Created successfully",
    "news_data": {
        "name": "abc",
        "description": "hello everyone",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "phone": "9097817522",
        "classified_id": 102
    }
}
```

And here is my js file where I am fetching the json data.

```
success: function(data) {
    var arr = data.data;
    var htmlText = '';

    for ( var key in arr ) {
        htmlText += '<div onclick="delete('+ arr[key].classified_id +')" ></div>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-name"> Name: ' + arr[key].name + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-loc"> Description: ' + arr[key].description + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Email: ' + arr[key].email_id + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Phone: ' + arr[key].phone + '</p>'; 
    }

    $('.feed-activity-list').append(htmlText);
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: must be classified I guess. on topic: Since you're doing a for loop, show us the complete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the loop if you're identifying the keys individually:

```
var arr = data.news_data;
var htmlText = '';
htmlText += '<div onclick="delete(' + arr.classified_id + ')" ></div>';
htmlText += '<p class="user-name"> Name: ' + arr.name + '</p>';
htmlText += '<p class="user-loc"> Description: ' + arr.description + '</p>';
htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Email: ' + arr.email_id + '</p>';
htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Phone: ' + arr.phone + '</p>';
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ern3ca12/4/)

Comment: Thanks @Andy for your suggestion, i got the solution what i want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "classification Created successfully",
    "news_data": {
        "name": "abc",
        "description": "hello everyone",
        "email_id": "abc@gmail.com",
        "phone": "9097817522",
        "classified_id": 102
    }
};
var arr = [];
    arr.push(data.news_data);
    var htmlText = '';

    for ( var key in arr ) {
        htmlText += '<div onclick="delete('+ arr[key].classified_id +')" > classified_id: ' + arr[key].classified_id + '</div>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-name"> Name: ' + arr[key].name + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-loc"> Description: ' + arr[key].description + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Email: ' + arr[key].email_id + '</p>';
        htmlText += '<p class="user-desc"> Phone: ' + arr[key].phone + '</p>'; 
    }

    $('.feed-activity-list').append(htmlText);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/10zxoxLq/1/)**

Comment: @ Sam you will need loop if you `news_data` have more `object`